# View count of deleted questions

Tags: support, deleted-questions, views

My deleted questions continue to count new views. I know that they can be seen by moderators and 10K+ users.

If other people try to open a deleted question (and only see the "error page"), is it counted in the views?

Comment: Link to an example please?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd : Here is [an example](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/139078/a-combinatorial-total-space-for-torsion-free-finitely-generated-groups)

Comment: On a hunch, I would say that it was only cache in action e.g. the view count is updated only once in X minutes so the final count was updated after the post was deleted but won't go any further.

Comment: [Example on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18584192/overload-function-by-stdenable-if), let's see if the view increase from 17. Update: yes, it does. :)

Comment: so we can get, announcer booster badges with deleted questions.... :o

Comment: @ZaheerAhmed I don't think so, there is most likely a check when badge should be awarded and it won't be awarded if the related post is deleted. Worth looking into it though!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it is, based on quick experiment with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18584192/447356). When I first viewed it, it had 17 views. Couple of minutes later, it jumped to 18 most likely my own view.

Viewing without being logged in, or without the "view deleted posts" privilege (10K rep), which gives the 404 page, is *not* counted. Confirmed by quick experiment with the OP here.

Comment: I also tried to open the page, I saw only the "error page", and it was not counted in the views, right ?

Comment: @SébastienPalcoux can't tell, now it's 20 (i.e. 2 more) but most likely those are other users with 10K on the main site.

Comment: @SébastienPalcoux quick, try [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18562563/i-want-to-use-linux-from-my-pendrive-so-that-i-can-use-it-in-different-computer) - right now it's 28 including my own view. :)

Comment: ShaWizDowArd: That's it !

Comment: @SébastienPalcoux still 28. Confirmed it's not affecting then.

Comment: I still have doubt about non 10K users' views. Because the views are cached.

Comment: @hims056 I viewed it, and the view count increased by 1 about one minute later. When Mr. Palcoux viewed, it did not increase over 2 minutes afterwards. That's all the proof I need, at least until a dev will show up to confirm or correct me... :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - Yeah you are correct. After 19 hours the view count is still 29 (28+mine). I also tested by viewing on incognito window yesterday. But the count is not increase for that.